# NPAPI mac plugin sharing commands with browser

Tags: c++, npapi

I have a NPAPI plugin running in Safari, Chrome and Firefox. I'm able to handle all key combinations with the event callback, but the problem I'm having is with certain key combinations.

In the plugin, I'm trying to use Command+O to fire the plugin's file open dialog, but the browser is also firing its open file dialog.

Supposedly, returning TRUE for event handling method should report the browser that the plugin handled the event, but I'm having no luck with that.

Answer (score 1):

You neglected to specify which OS you're on; based on the fact that you said "Command+O" instead of "Ctrl-O" I'm assuming you're on Mac.  The bad news is that on Mac, all events are passed to the plugin from the browser. If the browser doesn't choose to make it possible to override the handling of an event (and it sounds like this is the case) then there is probably nothing you can do about it, short of possibly using some OS hook to intercept the key event before the browser gets it, which seems risky.

On windows you might have a little more luck, since a windowed plugin should actually get events first before they are passed to the parent window and thus could intercept them. On Mac, though, it's all windowless and you get events when the browser feels like giving them to you.

Comment: Thanks taxilian. For the commands I've been working on, the browsers are indeed forwarding them, but still don't have the control to stop their action afterwards.

Comment: And short of somehow stopping it before it gets to the browser, there is no way to do so.